# How to call a python script with ajax in cherrypy app

Tags: python, ajax, cherrypy

I am trying to get the output from a python script and put it into a table in the html of my cherrypy app.

Example app:

```
import string, os
import cherrypy

file_path = os.getcwd()

html = """<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
http-equiv="content-type">
<title>CCMF</title>
<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='img/favicon.ico' />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function b1() {
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "b1.py",
            type: "POST",            
            dataType: "text"
        });
        request.done(function(msg) {
            $("#output").html(msg);          
        });
        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });
    }
</script>

</head>
<button onclick="b1()">call b1.py</button>
...
<td id = "output"; style="vertical-align: top; height: 90%; width: 100%;">
<--output goes here -->
</td>
...
</html>
"""
class ccmf(object):

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
    return html

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.server.socket_host = "127.0.0.1"
    cherrypy.server.socket_port = 8084
    config = {
         "/img": {
             "tools.staticdir.on": True,
             "tools.staticdir.dir": os.path.join(file_path, "img"),
         }
    }
    cherrypy.tree.mount(ccmf(), "/", config=config)
    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
```

and here's the example python script b1.py:

```
def b1():
    op = "ajax b1 pushed"
    print op
    return op

b1()
```

The ajax get's called but returns the failure alert. I have tried GET, POST, "text", "html", b1.py is in the same directory, no joy. All currently running on my local box.

Any hints greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think your design is flawed.  Try making b1 a function that returns a HTTPResponse.

Comment: That might be true as well, but it seems also to be a path issue. If I look under Tools>Web developer>Netwok in Firefox when I click the button, I get a 404. I have tried adding a cgi-bin directory and putting b1.py in there, and added "/cgi-bin": {
             "tools.staticdir.on": True,
             "tools.staticdir.dir": os.path.join(file_path, "cgi-bin") to the config, but it still thinks cwd/cgi-bin/b1.py doesn't exist.

Comment: OK, I ditched cherrypy and am serving the html file from apache. Now when I click the button, I get the contents of b1.py, instead of it being run and giving back the correct output. One step at a time lol.

Comment: Configured apache to run scripts and back to where I was before - 404 not found, despite it being there and all permissions correct. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are completely misunderstanding how modern, CherryPy's for instance, routing works. Unlike outdated approaches that were commonly employed with CGI and Apache's mod_* (mod_php, mod_python, etc.), where you directly point to the file containing the script with URL, modern routing is an application level activity.

Your application receives all requests and dispatches them according to the established method. CherryPy in that sense has two major approaches: [built-in object tree dispatcher](https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.2.6/concepts/dispatching.html#default-dispatcher) and [Routes adapter](https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.2.6/concepts/dispatching.html#other-dispatchers). For most simple and mid-level cases built-in dispatcher is fair enough.

Basically it can look like this.

*app.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import os

import cherrypy
from cherrypy.lib.static import serve_file


path   = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
    'server.thread_pool' : 8
  }
}

class App:

  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self):
    return serve_file(os.path.join(path, 'index.html')) 

  @cherrypy.expose
  @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
  def getData(self):
    return {
      'foo' : 'bar',
      'baz' : 'another one'
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/', config)
```

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
<title>CCMF</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $('button').on('click', function()
    {
      var request = $.ajax({'url': '/getData'});
      request.done(function(response) 
      {
        $('#foo').text(response.foo);
        $('#baz').text(response.baz);
      });
      request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) 
      {
        alert('Request failed: ' + textStatus);
      });
    })
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <button>make ajax call</button>
  <h1>Foo</h1>
  <div id='foo'></div>
  <h1>Baz</h1>
  <div id='baz'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that link supposed to return a 1GB file?

Comment: No, runnable.com was a service for server-side runnable code snippets (basically with a few clicks you could run the snippets from asnwer). It was acquired and closed a while ago as far as I can recall. Now doing `curl -v code.runnable.com` I see `301 Moved Premanently` to `https://www.wowrack.com/1GB.file`. Looks suspicious. Removed the link. Thanks for heads up.